# how to link same button to different urls

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table of subjects and onclick three buttons are created. The first one should link to the subject clicked, the second one reload the page and the last one should link to the connections page of the subject clicked, with other subjects.
For the first button I've used a switch on the id of the subjects assigning the proper url. I've tried the same for the "connections-button" but there must be a conflict because it still point to the subject url.
How can be fixed?

```
(function connessioni() {
        //Evidenzia Storia Singolo + Connessioni
        $('pre').hover(function () {
            $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
            $(this).css("background-color", "gray");
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            switch(id) {
                //Inizio Mafia
                case('riina'):
                    $('#contenuti').load('./biografie/Mafia/Riina.html img');
                    connessioni = $('#contenuti').attr('url',"./connessioni/riinacon.html");
                    singolo = $('#contenuti').attr('url', "./biografie/Mafia/Riina.html");
                break;
```

here the buttons

```
var firstbutton = $('<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="azzz">Storia Sua</button>').click(function(){

            var singolo = $('#contenuti').attr('url');
            location.href = singolo;
        });

        var secondbutton = $('<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="italiano">Azzera Storia</button>').click(function(){
            location.reload();
        });

        var lastbutton = $('<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="arancio">Connessioni</button>').click(function() {

            var connessioni = $('#contenuti').attr('url');
            location.href = connessioni;
        });
```

the complete code
https://jsfiddle.net/papalagi/sbjLwpam/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(
function setButtons(firstLink,lastLink){
    $('<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="azzz">Storia Sua</button>').click(function(){
        location.href = firstLink;
    };

    $('<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="arancio">Connessioni</button>').click(function() {
        location.href = lastLink;
    }
}

function connessioni() {
    //Evidenzia Storia Singolo + Connessioni
    $('pre').hover(function () {
        $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
        $(this).css("background-color", "gray");
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        switch(id) {
            //Inizio Mafia
            case('riina'):
                $('#contenuti').load('./biografie/Mafia/Riina.html img');
                setButtons( "./connessioni/riinacon.html","./biografie/Mafia/Riina.html");
                break;
```

In your code, you're setting the url and immediately overwriting it in:

```
connessioni = $('#contenuti').attr('url',"./connessioni/riinacon.html");
singolo = $('#contenuti').attr('url', "./biografie/Mafia/Riina.html");
```

Long story short, for your use case I'd consider just adding the eventlisteners after hovering over a pre, instead of writing data to the DOM and using that data in an universal listener.